# Is it a duplicate when the answer is given as background in another question?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

1. After asking Question X ([listing commands a package provides](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436278/how-do-i-list-commands-a-package-provides)), the OP explicitly states he's not looking for ~X (the opposite of Question X), and by way of background provides what the answer for ~X would be.
2. An hour later, someone asks [Question ~X](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436294/how-to-find-all-the-available-commands-in-a-package-before-installing-it/436330#436330).
3. This is promptly nominated for closing as a duplicate of Question X.

This feels like a duplicate. Yet when I also started to vote to close it, I became unsure since the answer is included merely as background to another question.

My question is whether this taken as a general case (apart from the merit or specifics of these two questions) is a truly a duplicate or not.

Update: The close vote was retracted and an answer has been provided, so maybe I have an answer; but comments/answers to this question are still welcome.

Comment: They seem perfect duplicates, how is one X and the other ~X? Anyway, they're both dupes of this one from two days ago too: [How can I know what programs does some apt-get package contents?](http://askubuntu.com/q/435168) (which is probably a dupe of an older one, *sigh*)